# UIPageCurl Transition like UIPageViewController between two view controllers?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol, uipageviewcontroller

I want transition similar to UIPageViewController transistion, Is it possible to achieve it.

```
SecondViewController* bvc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bvc animated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:bvc animated:YES];
```

As If now I have pageCurl(up) achieved via above code. But Actually want transition like pageTurn side wise. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You want an animation that follows your finger like in iBooks ? If yes, it's really complicated to reply. When I want that animation, I use UIPageViewController, otherwise I use a simple push or Modal animations.

Comment: Not finger but onclick of a button but transition from one view controller to another should be like pagecurl. Is this possible using model animation achieving pagecurl like iBOOK?